# To survive this puzzle, use lateral thinking

Tags: riddle

> I'll bring you in, I'm very strong.
>
> If you see flags, move right along.
>
> I ebb and flow, and don't you know?
>
> when high winds blow, with me you'll go.

Hint:

> This may not be the lateral thinking you were expecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you

> a tsunami/waves/riptides?

I'll bring you in, I'm very strong.

> Waves/tsunamis/riptides can come in and tsunamis are very powerful (waves can be too).

If you see flags, move right along.

> Flags on the beach act as warnings indicating it's unsafe to be on the beach at certain times (ie. if you see a danger: tsunami flag incoming, you should move right along and not be on the beach).

I ebb and flow, and don't you know?

> Tsunamis/waves/riptides can ebb and flow.

when high winds blow, with me you'll go.

> Tsunamis/waves/riptides can be accompanied by high winds, they sweep things in their path away with them wherever they travel.

The title

> means you need to travel laterally to the waves in order to survive giant waves crashing into a boat...? (or that tsunamis only occur at certain latitudes...?)

Comment: This is SUPER close, but to get all the clues right, you'll have to alter a bit!

Comment: Riptides it is - to escape a riptide, you have to swim laterally to the pull. Good work!

Answer (score 2):

You are

> Riptides

I'll bring you in, I'm very strong.

> Riptides are strong currents that drag you into the ocean

If you see flags, move right along.

> The beach will be marked with red flags if riptides are bad; stay out of the water

I ebb and flow, and don't you know?

> Riptides can ebb and flow

when high winds blow, with me you'll go.

> Riptides are more likely when seas are stormy, hence the high winds

Title:

> Swim laterally to escape a riptide! means

Comment: You are correct - I have to give the "accept" to @El-Guest since because all of the clues were answered, but I'll give you the +1 as well!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are a

> Sail

I'll bring you in, I'm very strong.

> Sails catch the wind, blowing boats in. They have to be strong enough to withstand storms

If you see flags, move right along.

> This is an indication of bouyes in water. If they have flags, they indicate what part of the water you can boat in.

I ebb and flow, and don't you know?

when high winds blow, with me you'll go.

> Sails catch the wind

Hint:

> This may not be the lateral thinking you were expecting... Lateral, as in latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: This isn't what I was thinking, but good interpretation! Keep trying - you're not going in an overly wrong direction.